# Binding a window created with the Cocoa Interface builder to a programmatically created one

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an Objective C application which starts with loading a window created with Interface Builder:

```
//in main()
[NSApplication sharedApplication];
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"MainMenu" owner:NSApp];
[NSApp run];
```

In MainMenu.xib I have a window with a button. I want to create programmatically the second window when that button is pressed.

```
  //in MainMenu.xib Controller.h
  @class SecondWindowController;

  @interface Controller: NSWindowController {
     @private
     SecondWindowController *sw;
  }
  - (IBAction)onButtonPress:(id)object;
  @end

//in MainMenu.xib Controller.m
#import "SecondWindowController.h"

@implementation Controller
- (IBAction)onButtonPress:(id)object {
  sw = [[SecondWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SecondWindow"];
  [sw showWindow:self];
  [[self window] orderOut:self];
}
@end
```

Where SecondWindowController inherits from NSWindowController. In SecondWindowController.h I have:

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow*)window {
  self = [super initWithWindow:window];
  if (self) {
    NSRect window_rect = { {custom_height1, custom_width1}, 
                           {custom_height2,    custom_width2} };
    NSWindow* secondWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] 
                         initWithContentRect:window_rect
                         styleMask: ...
                         backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                         defer:NO];                         
  }
  return self;
}
```

And in the SecondWindow.xib I have nothing. When the button of the first window is pressed the first window disappears and the application closes. The reason I don't want to use the Interface builder for the second window is that I want to programmatically initialize it. Is this possible and if so what is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: That second window controller needs to be an instance variable so it's doesn't go out of scope in `onButtonPress:`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is, I forgot to mention it...

Comment: I have no window object in SecondWindow.xib, I thought I should create the window in the code. Should I add one?

Comment: No, see my answer.  I was confused by your contradictory code and requirements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was initially confused with your use of `initWithWindowNibName:@"SecondWindow"` which will attempt to load the window from a NIB file, which you later mention you don't want to do.

Please use this to create your window:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonPress:(id)object {
    if (!sw)
        sw = [[SecondWindowController alloc] init];
    [sw showWindow:self];
    [[self window] orderOut:self];
}
```

Which will avoid creating multiple copies of the window controller, which you don't want (if you do then you'll need to store them in an array).  Note the name `sw` is incorrect by convention; use either `_sw` or create setter/getter methods and use `self.sw`.

Initialize `SecondWindowController` like this:

```
- (id)init {
    NSRect window_rect = NSMakeRect(custom_x, custom_y,
                                    custom_width, custom_height);
    NSWindow* secondWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] 
                         initWithContentRect:window_rect
                         styleMask: ...
                         backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                         defer:NO];                         

    self = [super initWithWindow:secondWindow];
    if (self) {
         // other stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note: your variable names for origin/size of the new window were wrong; please review them.